# How to calculate two input form fields and put the value in another without submitting the form using jquery with JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf-2.2

I have three fields called quantity, rate and total amount. whenever i enter rate and quantity field, both values should multiply and displayed in total amount column without refreshing the page. for this, i used jquery but not getting output. where i did the mistake and what is the root cause....

This is my JSF page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>ACIM</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/global.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"
        target="head" />
    <h:outputScript target="head">
     $ = jQuery;
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".input").keyup(function(){
              var val1 = +$("#myForm\\:quantity").val();
              var val2 = +$("#myForm\\:rate").val();
              $("#myForm\\:totalAmount").val(val1+val2);
         }); 
    });
    </h:outputScript>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="myForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">

            <h:outputText value="Quantity: " />
            <h:inputText id="quantity" value="#{myBean.quantity}">
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="rate" />
            <h:inputText id="rate" value="#{myBean.rate}">
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="totalAmount " />
            <h:inputText id="totalAmount" value="#{myBean.totalAmount}"
                disabled="true">
            </h:inputText>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once you have fixed your jQuery selectors, you can change `(val1+val2)` to `(val1*val2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a very small mistake; `$(".input")` selects all elements with `class="input"`. So either give your `inputText`'s this `styleClass` (`styleClass="xxx"` gets output as `class="xxx"` in html), or use the selector `$("input")` instead, which will select all html `<input>`-tags.